# Php artisan migrate doesn't work in laravel project

Tags: laravel

[image]

I created a new laravel project, I set the db data in .env file and I've created 2 new tables but when i run php artisan migrate doesn't return me nothing, it continue to load a migration endlessy.

I'm sure that the db credential i .env are correct, I'm using phpmyadmin and as host in .env i wrote mysql

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('matricola');
            $table->string('nome');
            $table->string('cognome');
            $table->string('luogo_nascita');
            $table->date('data_nascita');
            $table->string('incarico');
            $table->string('indirizzo');
            $table->integer('cap');
            $table->string('città');
            $table->string('provincia');
            $table->string('nazionalità');
            $table->string('codice_fiscale')->unique();
            $table->string('telefono')->unique();
            $table->string('email_personale')->unique();
            $table->string('email_aziendale')->unique();
            $table->string('banca');
            $table->string('iban')->unique();
            $table->integer('ore_contratto');
            $table->integer('giorni_ferie_anno');
            $table->integer('ore_permesso_annuali');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
};
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! what do you meant by *"it continue to load a migration endlessy?"* is the table are getting created? any error message? is it just stuck with empty message? can you check what are the code in the migrations?

Comment: @BagusTesa any error message, is stuck, I share you the migration code

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You can then start writing an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [mre] to improve it before submitting it.

Comment: Share your console command and screen. Php is not meant to be `stuck` without an infinite loop or a heavy performance code or waiting for input. So what else did you modify in your Laravel installation ?

Comment: @LeonardoGori we can answer your question if you give enough details from the start and avoid having to answer each comment bit by bit. How to do that ? well that is what the [tour] and other links i shared are for.

Comment: @N695 when I run php artisan migrate on my terminal start the migration endlessy, maybe it's a problem of connection on db server but it don't return error

Comment: and don't create nothing on db

Comment: @LeonardoGori pardon my grammars, but could you share with us your laravel and php version, your OS, and mysql version? also, if possible a screenshot that shows the console stuck. oh right, make sure no you dont have `php artisan serve` running on the background.

Comment: @BagusTesa php 8.2, Laravel Framework 9.48.0, OS windows 11, mysql 8.0, i  haven't  php artisan serve

Comment: click on "enter image description here" to see the img

Comment: "_and as host in .env i wrote mysql_" `DB_CONNECTION` should be set to `mysql`, not the host. `DB_HOST` should be `127.0.0.1` (or `localhost` or the IP of your MySQL server)

Comment: I wrong to explain,  DB_CONNECTION is mysql DB_HOST is localhost

Comment: "_and I've created 2 new tables_" Those should be created by the migrations. If there's no useful data in your tables you could try to run `php artisan migrate:fresh`. CAUTION!! this will drop tables and thus remove the data within the tables! Maybe make a backup before running it

Comment: @brombeer maybe I'm explained bad, i haven't tables in my db, i have a migration in my app and i can't migrate it

Comment: Do the default Laravel migrations run successfully? When you create a new Laravel project?

Comment: @brombeer no, default migration doesn't run successfully, same problem .

Comment: Strange. Do you have other Laravel projects that have the same problem? Do you have other projects that _don't_ have that problem? Restart your shell? Restart your PC? Have you tried using a different folder? (one outside of your "OneDrive" folder, might be there's something strange going on) Is the MySQL server on the same machine? Can you access it using phpMyAdmin or the likes?

Comment: @brombeer This is my first project in laravel with this pc and this xampp server, i've tryied to create another project in another folder but there is the  same problem, xampp server is on the same machine , i'm working in local

Comment: @LeonardoGori Note that xampp is not the best option for locally running Laravel applications. Valet or Docker will be better options.

Answer (score -1):

I think you creatd migration manually if that's the case then I would recommend to
use artisan commands to generate migration like

```
php artisan make:migration Create_users_table
```

this will create a migration template which will look like this

```
 <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
}
}
```

Comment: No, I've created the migration with artisan command

Comment: In newer laravel versions the classname is replaced by `return new class`. This is because before you could have naming conflicts.

Comment: regenerate your project i created new project and works fine here...